# Radius Authentication error between Active Directory NPS - Aruba 2930f

Tags: authentication, switch, radius, nps, aruba

I am trying to configure Radius authentification using NPS backend. I have configured both ends but it does not seem to work.I am not sure if this is even correct. Kindly help.

NPS Config:

> I have added my switch info under Radius Clients by giving the
> ip-address and shared secret key. Under Connection request policy I
> have specified the ip-address of the switch as condition. Under
> Network Policy I have specified the Active directory user groups and
> service-type is set to administrative.

Aruba 2930f switch config:

> radius-server host  key
> aaa authentication ssh login radius local  aaa authentication ssh
> enable radius local

I can ping Radius server and the switch.
I can only login as a local user and not as AD user

Answer (score 0):

We have a setup like it, in our connection request, the only condition is "NAS Port Type" with a value of "Wireless - IEEE 802.11 OR Wireless - Other".

Answer (score 0):

I created a new connection request policy under Policies in NPS.
Under conditions I have mentioned only the ip-address of the client.
Right click NPS-Server Stop and then start again.
It worked.